# Sum values in a dict of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, set

I have what might be a simple task and I tried several solutions but can't seem to figure it out.

I have a dict of sets containing gene names and corresponding positions as sets like:

```
gene_nr_snp = {'gene1: {3,9}, gene2: {2,3,1}, gene3: {1}}
```

I want to return a dict with the gene name and the corresponding summed value.

I tried the following:

```
gene_values = {}

for gene, snp in gene_nr_snp.items():
    for i in snp: # iterate the values in each set
        snp_total = 0
        snp_total += i
        gene_values[gene].add(snp_total)
```

This is returning the same set of values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension and the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
gene_values = {gene: sum(snp) for gene, snp in gene_nr_snp.items()}
```

Your attempt fails because you set the `snp_total` variable to `0` for every value in `snp`, thus failing to sum anything. You then seem to treat `gene_values[gene]` as a set but the dictionary starts empty, so you'll get a `KeyError`. A working version would be:

```
gene_values = {}

for gene, snp in gene_nr_snp.items():
    snp_total = 0
    for i in snp: # iterate the values in each set
        snp_total += i
    gene_values[gene] = snp_total
```

but the `sum()` function makes the inner loop rather more verbose than needed; the whole loop body could be replaced by `gene_values[gene] = sum(snp)`.